# R: how to use the log scale in the function symbols( )

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame with variables a, b, c

I want to use `symbols()` function to plot `b` against `a` such that `c != 0`, and create circles where the area of the circle is proportional `c`.  Use a log scale for both axes.

This is what I did:

```
symbols(a[!c == 0], b[!c == 0], log = "xy",
        inches=1/3, xlim=c(1e2, 1e11), ylim=c(1, 1e9), circles = c)
```

And I got:

```
Error in symbols(a[!c == 0], b[!c ==  : 
 x/y/parameter length mismatch

In addition: Warning messages:
1: "log" is not a graphical parameter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your `log = "xy"` isn't working, but your `x/y/parameter` problem is because your parameter `circles = c` is longer than your `x` and `y`: it includes `c` even when `c` is 0. So this should work:

```
symbols(a[!c == 0], b[!c == 0], log = "xy",
        inches=1/3, xlim=c(1e2, 1e11), ylim=c(1, 1e9), circles = c[c != 0])
```

As a work-around to get the log-scales, set up an empty plot first, then add the symbols

```
plot(NA, NA, type = "n", xlim=c(1e2, 1e11), ylim=c(1, 1e9), log = "xy")
symbols(x = a[!c == 0], y =  b[!c == 0], 
        inches=1/3, circles = c[c != 0], add = T)
```

One other note: you say your data is in a data.frame, but then you use just the variables in your call. This makes it seem like you've `attach`ed your data frame. I would avoid that if I were you. It saves some typing, but it runs the risk of hard-to-find bugs where you modify either the attached variables or the original data.frame and they don't match anymore.